# Julia memo-izing

Tags: julia, wolfram-mathematica, dynamic-programming

In *Mathematica* if you want a function to remember its values, it is syntactically quite painless. For example, here is the standard example - Fibonacci:

```
fib[1] = 1
fib[2] = 1
fib[n_]:= fib[n] = fib[n-1] + fib[n-2]
```

Is there some syntactically pleasant way to do this in Julia? Part of what it makes it more involved is the type system - here is an implementation for a single untyped arg:

```
function memoizeany(func)
    thedict = Dict()
    return (a)-> memoizeanyaux(a, func, thedict)
end

function memoizeanyaux(a, func, thedict)
    if haskey(thedict, a)
        return thedict[a]
    end
    res = func(a)
    thedict[a] =res
    return res
end
```

Doing this for every type signature seems a little painful, and presumably the most Julia way to do this is with a `@memoize` macro, but that does not actually answer the question. Surely this has come up before.

Comment: related package: https://github.com/colinfang/Memoize.jl

Comment: @Gnimuc Thanks! I actually found it after asking the question, but it seems to not address the main issues (it uses an untyped dict, at a quick glance).

Comment: I just foud this other Memoize: https://github.com/colinfang/Memoize.jl (*Type inference friendly generic function memoization*) havent tried it yet myself.

Comment: And here is the one that is a registered package but lacks inference friendliness: https://github.com/simonster/Memoize.jl

Comment: @SalchiPapa Cool! I will check it out.

Comment: In JuliaCollections: https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Memoize.jl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I need to use functions that use persistent memory, I simply create `struct`s and overload the `call` notation to make them functors. For the example you provide, I would write the Fibonacci sequence as

```
struct MyFib{T<:Real}
  n::Vector{T}

  function (::Type{MyFib})(::Type{T} = Int) where T
    new{T}([0, 1])
  end

  function (m::MyFib{T})() where T
    result = sum(m.n)
    m.n .= [result, m.n[1]]
    return result
  end
end

m = MyFib()

for n in 1:10
  @show n, m()
end
```

This way of using `struct`s is generic enough for me to encapsulate anything I need in my computations. Plus, because it is strictly typed using the parameter `T`, it is efficient, too.

Then, for the above example, you can also use some parametric function and function recursion, that would hopefully benefit from the integer constant propogation in `v0.7` to get as efficient as its templated counterpart in `C++`:

```
myfib(::Val{0}) = 0
myfib(::Val{1}) = 1

function myfib(::Val{N})::Int where N
  return myfib(Val{N-1}()) + myfib(Val{N-2}())
end

# or, as a single liner, as per crstnbr's comment,
myfib(::Val{N}) where N = myfib(Val{N-1}()) + myfib(Val{N-2}())

# and, with some syntactic sugar, thanks to SalchiPapa,
myfib(n::Int) = myfib(Val{n}())

for n in 1:10
  @show n, myfib(n)
end
```

I assume the latter one is more friendly for your example, as compared with the Mathematica version. But it is not as generic as the former, and you would be putting some stress on the compiler as it is a compile-time technique.

Comment: Why not just `myfib(::Val{N}) where N = myfib(Val{N-1}()) + myfib(Val{N-2}())`, why so lengthy?

Comment: Sure, we can write it that way. It does not change the way `julia` interprets the things and compiles them, though. Let me modify the answer.

Comment: Thanks! That is quite enlightening - much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome, @IgorRivin. Glad that it helped... Cheers! :)

Comment: You could also add another method for the last example `myfib(n::T) where {T<:Int} = myfib(Val{n}())` so the user now has only to do: `myfib(n)` instead of: `myfib(Val{n}())`.

Comment: @SalchiPapa, I would rather have `myfib(n::Int)` in this case, as `isempty(subtypes(Int)) == true`.